# Five letters in a row

Tags: riddle, word

A sequence of letters, 5 long. The first 4 will burn you to a crisp. The last 4 will injure you too. But all 5 are sure to charm.

Comment: Very nice @JnBrymn. These are short,sweet and non complicated

Comment: @DEEM A sequence of letters, 6 long. The first 4 make an urgent request. The last 4 help you relax. But all 6 are sure to please.

Comment: Another good one @JnBrymn. That would have worked just as well.

Comment: @Jnbrymn  Is the answer below correct? If yes then please accept it. If not, please consider giving another hint.

Comment: Five letters. The first 4 will scar you. The last 4 show you care. All of them will scare you. Did I get the format right? :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> CHARM : the first four (CHAR) will burn you, the last four (HARM) will injure you, and all five (CHARM) is self-explanatory.